# Not Quasicoherent Sheaf on $\mathbb{P}_k ^1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $\mathbb{P}_k ^1$ the projective line as scheme over a field $k$ (therefore two glued copies of  $\mathbb{A}_k ^1$. I'm looking for an example of a sheaf on $\mathbb{P}_k ^1$ which isn't quasicoherent.

Comment: The constant sheaf $\mathbb{Z}$. Or maybe you want an $\mathcal{O}_X$-module, then take the sheaf $j_!\mathcal{O}_U$ where $j:U\rightarrow X$ is the inclusion of any proper open subset.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I was originally looking for a $\mathcal{O}_X$-module.

Comment: What du you mean with the notation $j_! \mathcal{O}_U$? Which kind of sheaf operation is it?

Comment: Extension by zero. $j_!\mathcal{F}$ is the sheaf associated to the presheaf $V\mapsto \mathcal{F}(V)$ if $V\subset U$ and $0$ otherwise.